# SQL query to count duplicate values at row level

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have just stated using SQL query and hoping some one expert in SQL can help me to solve this puzzle.

The master table is as following

Table

```
Name    Col1  Col2  Col3  Col4  col5
-------------------------------------
John    T24   T24   T24   T97   J00
Tom     T24   J01    -      -     -
James   T24   L09    -    N78   T97
John    -     -     L56    -    T24
```

I am looking for SQL queries syntax to get the following two results "outcome table 1" and "Outcome table 2"

In the first query I am looking for how many times T24 or T97 appear for John in the same row. In the second query, how many times T24 or T97 appeared in the whole column for the same name. I have shown the example tables below as outcome table 1 and Outcome table 2

Outcome table 1

```
Name   T24    T97     Sum of both
-------------------------------------
John   3       1       4
Tom    1       0       1
James  1       1       2
```

Outcome table 2

```
Name  T24    T97     
----------------
John   2       0      
Tom    1       0    
James  1       1
```

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: What have you done in order to solve it by yourself first?

Comment: I am not sure what kind of query has been written in the past, as i have just started the job. I have just started using SQL and not sure how to get this result.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: SQL Server management studio 2012

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Select Name
     , sum( case Col1 when 'T24' then 1 else 0 end) +
       sum( case Col2 when 'T24' then 1 else 0 end) +
       sum( case Col2 when 'T24' then 1 else 0 end) +
       sum( case Col3 when 'T24' then 1 else 0 end) +
       sum( case Col4 when 'T24' then 1 else 0 end) as T24
     , sum( case Col1 when 'T97' then 1 else 0 end) +
       sum( case Col2 when 'T97' then 1 else 0 end) +
       sum( case Col2 when 'T97' then 1 else 0 end) +
       sum( case Col3 when 'T97' then 1 else 0 end) +
       sum( case Col4 when 'T97' then 1 else 0 end) as T97

     , sum( case Col1 when 'T24' then 1 else 0 end) +
       sum( case Col2 when 'T24' then 1 else 0 end) +
       sum( case Col2 when 'T24' then 1 else 0 end) +
       sum( case Col3 when 'T24' then 1 else 0 end) +
       sum( case Col4 when 'T24' then 1 else 0 end) +
       sum( case Col1 when 'T97' then 1 else 0 end) +
       sum( case Col2 when 'T97' then 1 else 0 end) +
       sum( case Col2 when 'T97' then 1 else 0 end) +
       sum( case Col3 when 'T97' then 1 else 0 end) +
       sum( case Col4 when 'T97' then 1 else 0 end) as SumOfBoth
from Table
group by Name
```

And learn more about [Case here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx).